# PHP Curl fetching video source urls from a video page using interface but not playing on html5 video player

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a new code and trying to fetch video source urls from pornhub video page using curl with interface.

This code was running ok few days back but i think pornhub has changed something on their streaming server and it has stoped working. My code still running on my pc's localhost but when i run in on server, i got 403 error

```
function get_site_html_string($url, $cookie=NULL, $referer = NULL, $timeout = CURL_TIMEOUT){

    $ip = 'x.x.x.x'
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 6000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, CURL_PROGRESS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    if ($referer) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }
    if ( $cookie ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    }
    $string = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo var_dump(curl_error($ch));
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $string;
}


function get_video_url_pornhub($url=''){
    $html = get_site_html_string($url);
    preg_match_all('/quality":"(.*?)","videoUrl":"(.*?)"/', $html, $matches_url);
    foreach ($matches_url[2] as $k => $v) {
        if (trim($v) != '') {
            $videos[$matches_url[1][$k]] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }           
    ksort($videos);
    return $videos;
}


$url = 'https://www.pornhub.org/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5d27619512bda';
$videos = get_video_url_pornhub($url);
print_r($videos);

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="<?php echo $videos[480] ?>" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

My code is successfully returning video source urls and it is working perfect when i try my pc without any interface but when i run this code on server, on video player or try to access (like wget using same interface or curl that url) i am getting error 403. (Sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0):

Did u find an solution> I think Cloudflare blocks it..